# Unable to identify extjs date field with partial ID

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, extjs, datefield

I’m working on an application in `ExtJS`, which is very dynamic in nature. I’m using selenium Webdriver, I could able to locate text fields, combo boxes in the page using the Partial ID (Contains, Startwith etc…), but unable to locate the Date field in the same page (Note: Only one date field exist in the page.). Please  help me to identify this date field object.

I could able to access the combo box using the below code:

**`WebElement comb = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//input[contains(@id, ‘combo’)]”));`**

Tried with the below and unable to locate the datefield:

**`WebElement dateBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//input[contains(@id, ‘datefield’)]”));`**

**HTML Details:**

`<input id=”datefield-1217-inputEl” data-ref=”inputEl” type=”text” role=”textbox” size=”1″ name=”dateOfBirth” maxlength=”10″ class=”x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-text-default x-form-invalid-field x-form-invalid-field-default” autocomplete=”off” componentid=”datefield-1217″>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution. Added Javascript in the code

```
JavascriptExecutor jsexc3 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

jsexc3.executeScript("Ext.getCmp('Componentname').queryById('formname').down('#itemId').setValue('"10/10/1990"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS has an existing feature to retrieve the element by ext id (which may be different from the HTML elementID). But once you know the ext id for the element you can use this ext function to retrieve the element id: `Ext.getCmp("your-Ext_id").getInputId()` and then you can use it in this way to get the HTML element:

```
document.getElementById(Ext.getCmp("your-Ext_id").getInputId());
```

Please look at this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jvh)